# After installed pnp4nagios,icons don't show up

Tags: icons, nagios

I installed pnp4nagios, and after that i have got this. nagios and pnp4nagios is fine,but the icons don't show up.

[image]

is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What Nagios core and pnp4nagios versions do you use? 
I think that the print screen you provide is from the pnp4nagios page. Usually the image folder is  /usr/local/pnp4nagios/share/media/images e.g. ...pnp4nagios/media/images/stats.png
You may right click in missing icons to find their path.
Do you have such a directory with images inside it?